# How to config rockDB StateBackend parameter for specific keyed state in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Flink job using RocksDBStateBackend.

Thera are several ProcessFunctions and each of them use MapState.
Suppose one of the MapStates is rather small: 200~300MB, and I want to ensure high read qps. I want to config enough block cache size for the MapState, while other MapStates use managed memory of task slot, So that total memory in block cache won't grow too much.

```
  public static class MyProcessFunction1 extends KeyedProcessFunction<Integer, String, Long> {

    // this map state will store lot of kv pairs,
    // so I hope to config rocksdb column family options
    //   optimized for write
    private transient MapState<byte[], byte[]> largeMapState;
  }

  public static class MyProcessFunction2 extends KeyedProcessFunction<Integer, String, Long> {

    // this map state will store dozen of kv,
    // so I hope to config rocksdb column family options
    //   optimized for small db, further more I want this
    //   map state do not share managed memory with other state.
    private transient MapState<byte[], byte[]> smallMapState;
  }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just add some code to help illustrating my problem.